# Eureka replicas unavailable

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have problem with configuring eureka replicas :

Eureka service :

```
@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class DiscoveryService {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DiscoveryService.class, args);
    }
}
```

bootstrap.properties

```
spring.application.name=discovery
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
```

I also have two yml files

for server 1 runing on 8761

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone:http://localhost:8762/eureka/
eureka.client.registerWithEureka:false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry:false
```

for server 2 running on 8762

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone:http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.client.registerWithEureka:false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry:false
```

I can enter both dashboards, but I see that both instance have this:

```
registered-replicas http://localhost:8761/eureka/
unavailable-replicas    http://localhost:8761/eureka/,
available-replicas
```

Why is that ?

Comment: Where are you seeing the information about the available and unavailable replicas?  Do you have a sample project that reproduces the issue that we can take a look at?

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Comment: Try going through this blog for setting up eureka replica, this may help https://troublemakersacademy.com/2020/04/redundant-eureka-servers-eureka-db-replicas/

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing your eurekas don't register themselves with `localhost` as their hostnames so this is why you're seeing them as unavailable in the eureka dashboards. Eureka uses this pattern a lot, it matches the service url with the caller hostname to determine replication context.

Peer eureka nodes are fetched in `com.netflix.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes::resolvePeerUrls` from the list of eureka service urls (`eureka.client.serviceUrl` key or DNS based). Later on, this list is matched against currently registered eureka applications in `com.netflix.eureka.util.StatusUtil::getStatusInfo` by using the hostname to get the replica statuses.

Since your application most likely doesn't register itself with `localhost`, it'll get added to the unavailable replicas.

Comment: So you are saying we need to set `eureka.instance.hostname=localhost` ?

Comment: I changed `eureka.instance.hostname=peer0` to `eureka.instance.hostname=machine_ip`. I also had `eureka.client.register-with-eureka` set to false, so I had to change that to true. Now it works. thanks

Comment: The hostname used in `eureka.client.serviceUrl` should match the one in `eureka.instance.hostname` for the eureka server.

Comment: thanks, bro. I was struggling with this for a long time. Replaced my Host IP based configuration to hostname based and now it works like a charm.